# $\frac{(x-3)^2}{2} + \frac{(y-4)^2}{3} + \frac{(z-3)^2}{2} \leq 1 ; x \geq 3, y \geq 4, z \leq 3$

Tags: calculus

$\frac{(x-3)^2}{2} + \frac{(y-4)^2}{3} + \frac{(z-3)^2}{2} \leq 1 ; x \geq 3, y \geq 4, z \leq 3$

Task is to describe this set in terms of open, closed, and connected. After drawing the picture i would say that set is closed and connected, but i am having trouble describing it mathematically. Any help, if I am right at first place that it is closed and connected?

Comment: It is one octant of a prolate spheroid (interpreted as a solid, not a surface). Yes it is closed and connected.

Comment: oh yes sorry ill correct it

Comment: 1) Is your question just "is it closed and connected?", or does the "task" include to prove it? 2) Anyway, please [include your attempts *in your post*](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).